# Institute Name in @masterthesis Citations

Tags: biblatex

I need to cite master thesis and the lecture notes into a document. But the problem with `@masterthesis` and `@unpublished` citations is they don't print an institution name in the `pdflatex` output of bibliography.

```
`\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=true, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@masterthesis{bhgt,
title={Bike Model},
author={Fris},
year={2016},
school={University A},
address={XXX}
}
@unpublished{Map,
title = {Electrical Engineering Book},
author={Koch},
howpublished = {Lecture Notes},
Institution= {University B},
year = {2015}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Citation Test:  \cite{bhgt} and \cite{Map}
\printbibliography

\end{document}`
```

I get this bibliography output:

> [1] Fris. Bike Model. XXX, 2016.
>   [2] Koch. “Electrical Engineering Book”. Lecture Notes. 2015.

Any suggestions, how we can also print an institute name?

Comment: What kind of bibliography package do you use? Do you really use `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? Please consider adding an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we can see how you are creating your bibliography, a solution may very well depend on your setup. In `biblatex` you'll have to use `institution` for the `@thesis` type, but `school` is still supported as an alias.

Comment: There is a `,` missing after `bhgt`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Use `@mastersthesis` (with an `s` after `master`) instead of `@masterthesis` (which doesn’t exist and probably defaults to some other type), then `school` will appear.
2. The entry type `@unpublished` doesn’t support `school`, so I’d suggest using `note` instead, as is recommended in the `biblatex` documentation:

   > Use the fields `howpublished` and `note` to supply additional information in free format, if applicable.

   You could also use the field `addendum`, which would appear at the very end.

   It would probably be more proper and clean to redefine the output of `@unpublished` to include `school`/`institution`, but as a one-off solution, this should be fine.

Here’s the output:

[image: output]

As a side note: The official field names in `biblatex` are `institution`, not `school`; and `location`, not `address`, but the latter ones do work as aliases.

Comment: Thanks. It Works. @doncherry But all other `bibliography` entries  are without `" "` and in `italic` form. Adding `s` in `@masterthesis` and `note` in `@unpublished` have made the text normal (instead of italic) and covered it with `" "` (it is also shown in the output you have posted).

Comment: Author names are in normal form but all `titles` are in `italic` form.

Comment: @ArslanYousaf `@unpublished` is quoted and upright in your MWE as well. You could change the type to `@misc` to get it in italics. `@mastersthesis` is indeed printed more like an `@article` than like a `@book`. You could add `\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` in the preamble to change that.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty, using `bibtex` together with `natbib`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{toto1.bib}
@PHDTHESIS{bhgt,
  title        = "Bike Model",
  author       = "Fris",
  year         = "2016",
  type         = "Master's Thesis",
  school       = "University A",
  address      = "XXX",
}
@UNPUBLISHED{Map,
  title        = "Electrical Engineering",
  author       = "Koch",
  note         = "Lecture Notes, University B",
  year         = "2015",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet{Map}
\citet{bhgt}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{toto1}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It has worked. But why do we need to write all text  within`""`?  @Denis

Comment: @ArslanYousaf Either that or `{Name},`.